# Create variables in a for loop

Tags: python, variables, for-loop

I am making a voting system with python 3 and I get the candidates for each position based on user input through tkinter. For the sake of this example I won't be using tkinter as it is unnecessary.

I have my candidates stored inside of lists when they are created. Since the user can create as many candidates as they want there is no way of knowing how many variables I need for the counting process. That is why I believe I need to use a for loop to create variables. How can I do that?

```
posOne = []
f = [x.strip() for x in candidates.split(',')]
for x in f1:
    posOne.append(x)

for z in posOne:
    #code to create a new variable
```

Then I'll need a way to target the created variables so when they receive a vote I can count +1

If you know of a better way to handle this please let me know, because this doesn't seem optimized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use a dictionary:

```
votes = {candidate.strip(): 0 for candidate in candidates.split(',')}
```

This is a dictionary comprehension that is equivalent to:

```
votes = {}
for candidate in candidates.split(','):
    votes[candidate.strip()] = 0
```

The when you get a vote for a candidate:

```
votes[candidate] += 1
```

To determine the winner:

```
winner = max(votes, key=votes.get)
```

e.g.:

```
>>> candidates = 'me, you'
>>> votes = {candidate.strip(): 0 for candidate in candidates.split(',')}
>>> votes
{'me': 0, 'you':0}
>>> votes[you] += 1
>>> winner = max(votes, key=votes.get)
>>> winner
'you'
```

Comment: I've never used dicts or maps yet, how would I determine the winner using this?

Comment: if you don't mind could you break down what each section of the code does, since I haven't used dicts or maps before it would greatly help me understand how to edit your answer for my actual program

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which is `dict` like object where values are counts:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> candidates = 'Jack, Joe, Ben'
>>> votes = Counter({x.strip(): 0 for x in candidates.split(',')})
```

Voting would be done like this:

```
>>> votes['Jack'] += 1
>>> votes['Jack'] += 1
>>> votes['Ben'] += 1
```

And [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) can be used to determine winner:

```
>>> votes.most_common(1)
[('Jack', 2)]
```